# How to redirect a subpage of one website to another domain?

Tags: wordpress, url, dns, cross-domain

My question is simple, let's say there is a website created by WordPress with its URL:cuaauc.com, and it has so many sub-pages, including one named cuaauc.com/contact/. I would like to redirect the cuaauc.com/contact/ to other content from my external domain test.com. I understand how to direct cuaauc.com to test.com, but I am not sure how to do the subpage situation.

Please give me some advice, or tell me if this is impossible to work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just what to set the link for the navigation item in your wordpress site (so that the button 'contact' directs to an external page), you can do this in wordpress backend under Design -> Menus and make the menu item an individual link and set the url.

You can also make a page-template (page-yourpage.php) and set the redirecting in your php file or include (php include or via iframe) the content of your target contact page.

There are also more ways to achieve this.

If you like you can write a little bit more about what you are exactly trying to achieve and why you want to have the contact page being seperated. This way the we can give you better help and can decide which method suits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks, I think the method number one would be the answer to my question. I will try it tomorrow see if it can work!

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

After Install an Activate plugin, go to **Tools > Redirection**
If you are using first time this plugin, you may have to set up this plugin by simply a few clicks.

Then you can add new Redirections rule by click on **Add New** button.
[image]